# What happens with a RISCV LOAD wider than there is memory left?

Tags: memory, assembly, riscv

What would be the behavior of the following program?

```
li t0, 0xFFFFFFFF
lw t1, 0(t0)
```

Is this implementation (MMU or execution environment) defined? I can't find any mention of this scenario in the RISC-V specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RISC-V privileged ISA classify Physical Memory into three types: Main Memory, I/O and Empty.

> Empty regions are also classified as I/O regions but with attributes
>   specifying that no accesses are supported.

The document goes on saying that contrary to Main Memory (which always support R/W) an I/O region, and therefore an Empty region, can specify which access are supported.

> I/O regions can specify which combinations of read, write, or execute accesses to which data widths
>   are supported.

Each region has one or more Physical Memory Attribute (PMA) that stated if the region is cached, support atomic operations, it is ordered and which data size is supported.

The PMA of a region must be checked by the hardware and if any constraint is violated a trap or an interrupt is reported:

> PMAs are checked for any access to physical memory, including accesses that have undergone virtual to physical memory translation. To aid in system debugging, we strongly recommend that, where possible, RISC-V
>   processors precisely trap physical memory accesses that fail PMA checks. Precise PMA traps might not always be possible, for example, when probing a legacy bus architecture that uses access failures as part of the discovery mechanism. In this case, error responses from slave devices will be reported as imprecise bus-error interrupts.

---

The specification doesn't impose any PMA on empty regions and doesn't define any PMA value, it explicitly states that

> As PMAs are tightly tied to a given physical platform’s organization, many details are inherently platform-specific, as is
>   the means by which software can learn the PMA values for a platform.

What happens when a non-existent RAM address is accessed is left to the specific *micro-architecture* defined by the implementation.

Usually the memory bus has pull-up/pull-down resistors. In such case reading from a non-existent address will result in a word made of ones or zeros and writing will be ignored.

Depending on the hardware the result can be anything, even an exception signalling a failed transaction on the bus.

Comment: The RISC-V Privileged Specification also defines the MMU and this case also affects the MMU. In such a case it must be clearly specified what should happen, otherwise this can lead to security issues.

Comment: @fsasm Thanks for pointing out the privileged ISA specs. Unless I misunderstood the question I don't think this involved the MMU as physical memory is accessed after all the MMU operations. Checking the specs also seems to confirm my statements: the hardware is required to check PMAs but PMAs are platform specific and so is the way to report a failed PMAs check. An interrupt is also clearly stated as a possible result of accessing an Empty region. I don't see what security issues could arise from accessing empty regions.

Comment: In case of unaligned addresses the processor needs to access two consecutive data words. If this isn't properly handled, the program can access bytes it shouldn't. Now imagine you could access the first bytes of the page table or other critical data structures.

Comment: @fasm I'm confident the CPU will discard all the unneeded bytes from the wider load and that in the eventuality that it is the SW that handle the load split, all the structure are properly aligned (as a word is either accessible or not for a specific program).